# Selecting data from 2 columns, both within a range of another row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a SDR (Software Defined Radio) project. My current set-up is processing FM transmissions and storing the results together with the GPS time in a table.

An example of the data;

```
FMMhz   Time
---------------------------------
90      2019-02-29 13:23:44.000
90,1    2019-02-29 13:24:44.000
89,9    2019-02-29 13:22:44.000
100     2019-02-29 13:24:44.000
107     2019-02-29 13:24:44.000
```

So far so good. The next step would be trying to query the data in order to get the values close to each other for both columns. In the instance above I would like to get the data from the top 3 rows since the FM-Mhz is in a 0,1 range and the Time within a 1 second range from the other records. The query should not return the 4th and 5th row due to FMMhz range is not meeting the criteria. I've tried to retrieve the results with the query listed below. However with no success.

```
SELECT *
FROM Testtabel a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Testtabel b
              WHERE b.FMMhz <> a.FMMhz 
                AND b.FMMhz >= a.FMMhz-.2 AND a.FMMhz + .2)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM Testtabel b
               WHERE b.Time <> a.Time
                 AND b.Time BETWEEN a.Time - .2 AND a.Time + .2)
```

Can somebody put me on the right track?

Comment: Did you try cross Apply?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds like you are looking to compare adjacent records in your table. In SQL Server this is done with a window function, in this case `LAG`. `LAG` will select data in the previous records as defined by the `ORDER BY` clause in the `OVER` clause. You can then compare the data and use it to filter out records that don't meet your criteria. Since you cannot use window functions in a `WHERE` clause, you can first select the data you want to compare into a CTE.

```
;with diff as
 (
  SELECT FMMhz, Time, LAG(FMMhz) OVER(ORDER BY FMMhz)prevFMMhz, LAG(Time) OVER(ORDER BY FMMhz)prevTime
  from Testtabel 
 )
select * 
from diff
where (prevFMMhz is null or FMMhz - prevFMMhz <=.1)
    and (prevTime is null or datediff(minute,  prevTime, time)<=1) --did you mean 1 minute range?
    order by FMMhz
```